# shell parameter substitution to rename files

Tags: shell, string

I need to rename filenames which starts with "foo" into "boo"

This is the script I used

```
#!/bin/sh


for f in *.jpg;
do

mv -- "{$f}" "${f/foo/boo}";


done
```

but when i run I get a bad substitution error. what is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `/bin/sh` as a shell, which seems to accept only plain sh features.
Advanced features like `${//}` are extensions only available in shells like bash.

Just change you shebang and everything should work.

Also have a look at `man rename` (sometimes called `prename` where `rename` is the one from util-linux). This should do exactly what you need:

```
rename 's/^foo/boo/' foo*.jpg
```

If you used `/bin/sh` intentionally you can use:

```
mv -- "$f" "boo${f#foo}"
```

Have a look at man sh for details.

Comment: if i have to use only the feature form /bin/sh , how do i do it?

Comment: i am getting mv cannot stat error

Comment: You had a typo in your original command `"{$f}"` should simply be `"$f"`.

Comment: `${//}` comes from `ksh` and is also available in `zsh`. It is not specific to `bash` nor does it originate there. Note that there exist two variants of `rename` available on Linux, one from `perl` one from `util-linux`.